# Do you want to view only the web content that was delivered securely - IE warning

Tags: php, internet-explorer, browser

When I load a webpage in IE, I get the below error,
"Do you want to view only the web content that was delivered securely". I know this is because I use "http" instead of "https" in some of the urls used to create the webpage. I want to remove this warning. I am also using php, is there any way I can remove the warning without changing any setting in the IE tools options, using php. I am also embedding a YouTube video which stops working if I change "http" to "https". Is there any solution to this problem. I want to do it on my end, so that the user doesnt have to change any of their settings when they visit the website.

Comment: There  seems to be a solution in the dupe

Comment: @Pekka - Yup, there's an interesting work-around in there. (Guessing it works as the YouTube player isn't swapped in until after the page is loaded as far as IE is concerened.)

Answer (score 3):

The only way to remove the warning is to ensure that *all* the referenced content is on a HTTPS connection.

It really is that simple.

As such, you'll have to either remove the YouTube link or use another video provider that streams over HTTPS. (Can't imagine there will be many of them due to the lack of demand for such a resource intensive operation.)

UPDATE - See the link @Pekka provided in a comment on your question for a workaround.

Comment: I understand that, but like I said my Youtube videos wont work if I change the url in the code I use to embed the video on my website.

Comment: @developer it may not be possible to do this with YouTube videos.